# Assigning id number as key of an array creates thousand other array with keys less than given nubmer

Tags: javascript

I want to group some array by number (idGrupy variable - integer) - in this case the number is 3355.
My code:

```
if (rezerwacjePosortowanePoGrupie['zgrupa'] === undefined) {
            rezerwacjePosortowanePoGrupie['zgrupa'] = new Array();
          }
          if (rezerwacjePosortowanePoGrupie['zgrupa'][idGrupy] === undefined) {
            rezerwacjePosortowanePoGrupie['zgrupa'][idGrupy] = new Array();
          }

          rezerwacjePosortowanePoGrupie['zgrupa'][idGrupy].push(item);
        }
```

JS does this:

[image]

Comment: please add the type of `rezerwacjePosortowanePoGrupie['zgrupa']` as well.

Comment: @NinaScholz I have this: if (rezerwacjePosortowanePoGrupie['zgrupa'] === undefined) {
                rezerwacjePosortowanePoGrupie['zgrupa'] = new Array();
              }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an object, instead of an array as default value.

```
rezerwacjePosortowanePoGrupie['zgrupa'] = rezerwacjePosortowanePoGrupie['zgrupa'] || {};
```

By using an array you get a sparse array with holes inside, because the greatest index increases the lenght of the array, if the array is smaller before.

```js
var array = [],
    object = {};

array[5] = 42;
object[5] = 42;

console.log(array); // sparse array with undefined
console.log(object);
```

Comment: I need it as an array because Angular's NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: you could generate an array with the data, like `[{ group: indexOrGroup, values: arrayItemsOdTheGroup }, ...]`, if that helps.